# Problema al hacer deploy en render

Tags: spring-boot, backend

Muy buenas... al intentar hacer un deploy de un proyecto en Render, me aparece este error:

```
Mar 17 07:23:10 PM  error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref tkr5j4tbk47hulhvtfwjg063b::mfmdtvnsnpasm28phmarycnxn: failed to walk /home/user/.local/tmp/buildkit-mount3724125671/target: lstat /home/user/.local/tmp/buildkit-mount3724125671/target: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Ahí te dice que no existe el archivo o el directorio. Es decir es más que todo por que no está encontrando ese archivo revisa en ese directorio si existe o no

Comment: No no, tampoco encontré ese directorio...
¿cómo puedo hacer para modificar el directorio?

esta es la información que contiene el dockerfile:

`FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk
#FROM amazoncorretto:19

LABEL MAINTEINER="briansabas"

COPY ./target/api-porfolio-brian-1.0.0.jar api-porfolio-brian-1.0.0.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/api-porfolio-brian-1.0.0.jar"]

EXPOSE 8080
`

Comment: al parecer es algo por el dockerfile que usas.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Etapa de construcción
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17-slim AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

# Copia el código fuente y compila el proyecto
COPY src ./src
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

# Etapa de producción
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim AS production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este _dockerfile_ a la pregunta? Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.